# Is there a simple way to transfer image from openMV to PC?

Tags: embedded, micropython, flir, openmv

I am working on the flir lapton3.5 with openMV. With the help of openMV, it's easy for me to get the thermal image from filr lapton3.5, don't have to concern about the complicated spi/iic agreement.

Well, I want to show the real-time thermal image in my PC's qt program, that means the thermal image need to transfer to the PC in the real time. But unfortunately, I didn't see an offical protogenetic way to get the image in PC. Though the image can be shown in the openmv ide, openmv doesn't seem to want user get the image. So anybody knows how to get the picture from openMV to PC?

Thanks very much!

Comment: OpenMV has a library for this with documentation which I found in their forum.

[OpenMV Remote Python Call Library](https://github.com/openmv/openmv/tree/master/tools/rpc)